# user login for dreamweaver

Tags: authentication, dreamweaver

I want to know if there is any way we can make a user login for dreamweaver, like the one in windows where users have to login to use their accounts or if there is any extensions available for the same. I want to use different settings and sites for different users.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, its a login for Dreamweaver itself not for a website. What we actually want to do is to build Sites with SVN (Using Version Control Option in DW) and have anyone sit on nay workstation.

The commit messages must be sent from the user currently occupying that workstation. Hence a login and passw during DWs startup would be great!

Answer (score 0):

There are many extensions that will do this for you. All cost. You can find them in the Exchanged hosted at Adobe.

BUT, DW hasbuilt in login/logout extensions. You can find them with the "Server Behaviors" panel. Expand the list of behaviors and you'll see "User Authentication". They should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user login for using dreamweaver but for that you need to have knowledge of some php and mysql. Create a user table using phpmyadmin.Creat a form which include two field Username and Password. Then you can use the insert menu>Data object>user Authentication.